# Add item into list with one line if statement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, one-liner

I have the following code:

```
a = True

x = [2, 7, 8]

print(x)

if a:
    x.append(10)
    
print(x)

# one line ???
y = [2, 7, 8 if a: 10]

print(y)
```

I'm trying to use if statement in one line, but I get invalid syntax. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to do: `y = [2, 7, 8, 10] if a else [2, 7, 8] `, see: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html, or a better link might be this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/724039

Comment: Why you want to do that?  - just curious.

Comment: @Luuk: thanks because point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user @Luuk it show [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/2030219) which tells some ways to use one line if statements, this helps me understand more about this code practice in python.